# Tailwind integration in stencil with Postcss slow down build speed

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss, stenciljs

H have a Stencil project to which I integrated Tailwind following this tutorial: https://ionic.io/blog/how-to-integrate-tailwind-css-into-your-stencil-project

Specifically, I followed the approach mentioned in the section "Using PostCSS" because it was the only one that didn't cause any issues during integration. However, using PostCSS significantly increases the build times of my project, whereas they are almost instantaneous if I don't use it.

Have any of you encountered the same issue?

This is my stencil.config.js

```
const purgecss = require("@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss")({
  content: ["./src//*.tsx", "./src//*.css", "./src/index.html"],
  defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_:/]+/g) || []
});

export const config: Config = {
  devServer: {
    reloadStrategy: 'hmr',
  },
  outputTargets: [… ],
  plugins: [
    dotenvPlugin(),
    inlineSvg(),
    sass({
      injectGlobalPaths: [
      'src/global/variables.scss',
    ]}),
  postcss({
      plugins: [
        require("postcss-import"),
        require("tailwindcss/nesting")("postcss-nesting"),
        require("tailwindcss")("./tailwind.config.js"),
        autoprefixer(),
          ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? [purgecss, require("cssnano")]
          : [])
      ]
    })
    ],
  ….
};
```